# "Can't use ACIRCLE as a function" Error in C programming

Tags: c

I don't get it, what am I doing wrong?
I tried changing the names of the variables but nothing is working, I keep getting the "Can't use ACIRCLE as a function" error... help?
Code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int Get_Radius(int R);
int Get_Length(int L);
float ACIRCLE(int R,float A);
int main(){
    int R,L;
    float A,Area,ACIRCLE;
    R=Get_Radius(R);
    L=Get_Length(L);
    Area=ACIRCLE(A);
    printf("%f",ACIRCLE);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
float ACIRCLE(int R,float A) 
{
    R=Get_Radius(R);
    A=R*R*3.14;
    return A;
}

int Get_Radius(int R)
{
    printf("Input the Radius of a circle:\n");
    scanf("%d",&R);
    return R;
}
int Get_Length(int L)
{
    printf("Input the Length of the square\n");
    scanf("%d",L);
    return L;
}
```

*edit*

So I edited the code as noted in the comments, now I don't get an error but whenever I type in the values the .exe file stops working. Can you please help?

Current code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int Get_Radius(int R);
int Get_Length(int L);
float ACIRCLE(int R,float A);
int main(){
    int R,L;
    float A,Area;
    R=Get_Radius(R);
    L=Get_Length(L);
    Area=ACIRCLE(A);
    printf("%f\n",Area);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


int Get_Radius(int R)
{
    printf("Input the Radius of a circle:\n");
    scanf("%d",&R);
    return R;
}
int Get_Length(int L)
{
    printf("Input the Length of the square:\n");
    scanf("%d",L);
    return L;
}
float ACIRCLE(int R,float A) 
{
    R=Get_Radius(R);
    A=R*R*3.14;
    return A;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help..

Comment: You are calling the ACIRCLE function just only with one parameter, But method signature has two parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You have a local variable with the same name as the `ACIRCLE` function, that takes precedence meaning you try to use the variable as a function.

So the solution is to not declare the `ACIRCLE` *variable* and the print the `Area` instead.

---

There are also some other problems, like you calling the `ACIRCLE` with only one argument, as noted by Dinidu in a comment. You also don't really need to pass any arguments to any function at all, instead declare them, as local variables inside the functions. And in the `main` function you don't need to call the `Get_Radius` or `Get_Length` functions.

Comment: I've done what you guys mentioned, thank you, but for some reason the .exe file stops working.
Edited question to show code.

Answer (score 1):

You defined ACIRCLE as a function, and as a variable inside main(); so compiler thinks that you are referring to the innermost ACIRCLE definition (that is the variable) when you are typing Area=ACIRCLE(A).
Obviously, this doesn't make sense for the compiler, and so the error comes out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn some basic of C, in this case: *functions*.

A function is an operation that can give you (*return*) something when you eventually feed it with some other things (*arguments*).

The form of the function is:

return_type name_of_function(argument1, argument2, ...)

you can feed in no arguments if you don't need to.

A function for calculating the area of a circle should be

```
float circlearea(float radius){
    float area = 2 * PI * radius* radius;
    return area;
}
```